# Can't able to integrate amazon lex bot v2 in web UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Amazon Cloud has launched a new version of lex v2. But there is no proper documentation to integrate web UI pointed to v2, If I go to the documentation of v2 to integrate the web UI it's showing me the same as v1.

I tried to implement the same way in v2 with this library https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui but it's not working for me.

It's returning me this error
`The specified resource 'XXXXX' does not exist. Choose another resource.`

Actually, in v2 I can't find Publish option in v2 to publish my bot.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `aws-lex-web-ui` now supports Lex v2 bots starting with [version 0.17.9](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/releases/tag/v0.17.9).

Answer (score 3):

After encountering the same issue, I finally managed to get rid of it.

You need to declare some parameters in the JSON config file, in section "lex", to declare that bot is V2

```
"lex": {
    "v2BotAliasId": "Your bot alias ID",
    "v2BotId": "Your bot ID",
    "botName": "Your bot name",
}
```

Declaring botName only is not enough, and the script will think you're trying to use a V1 bot instead of V2.

You need to publish a version of your bot and link an alias in Lex Console. In Lex Console, select your bot, go in "Bot Versions", and click on "Create version" button.
You also need to create a Cognito User Pool and a Cognito Identity Pool.